# Rebuilding Laravel migrations / scripting a database

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, migration

I currently have a laravel mysql database that I'd like other developers to receive both data and structure. However, not all database tables have been established beautifully through migrations.

I'm wondering what the best way to achieve this would be? Is it possible to reset any migrations and start over, or somehow script the database as it stands?

Comment: I just found this : https://beyondco.de/docs/laravel-masked-db-dump/schema-definition
Or you can use the command `php artisan schema:dump` and create some seeders (more work)
Also read this : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html

Comment: I'll take a look at those. Ideally, I'm looking for a set your environment variables and run php artisan migrate or other command to get your database installed.